# How to populate dropdownlist inside Modal popup with dynamic data in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to populate dropdownlist inside Modal popup with dynamic data in MVC. When I clicked on `Open`  the `DisplayModal` modal should display with updated data in dropdowmlist. My `Jquery` code is not displaying Modal popup with new data in dropdownlist.

View

```
     <table>
       <tr>
           <td>
              @Html.DisplayName("IT")
             </td>
             <td>
      <a class="LinkId" data-toggle="modal"  data-url="/Home/_ModalPopup?Page=1">Open</a>
        </td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
               <td>
                 @Html.DisplayName("Sales")
                   </td>
                    <td>
        <a class="LinkId" data-toggle="modal"  data-url="/Home/_ModalPopup?Page=2">Open</a>

                  </td>
                </tr>                            
        </table>
    @{Html.RenderAction("__MEmpModal"); }
```

Partial Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="DisplayModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, Model.CategoriesList, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>               
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
 $(document).on("click", '.LinkId', function (e) {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data("url"),
            type: "GET",
        }).done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("#DisplayModal").html(partialViewResult);
            $('#DisplayModal').focus();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your ajax call does not pass anything related to your `EmpViewModel model` parameter (therefore you should remove that). And it passes a query string value named `page` but the other parameter is named `id` - i.e. your `string Id` will always be `null` and your `if (Id==null)` block will always be executed. Its not clear what your want to do.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I want to display a dropdownlist with dynamic data.As you can see that there are 2 rows in the table and each has `Open` link. When I click on it, I want to display the same dropdown with different data inside.

Comment: Then read my previous comment - you are not sending a value for `Id`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Can you please guide me how to do this.

Comment: Read my comment! `data-url="/Home/_ModalPopup?id=1"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Sorry that was my silly mistake. I fixed that. Now I am getting the value in`partialViewResult` inside the script but modal does not popup. Then I tried `$("#DisplayModal").html(partialViewResult);` to ` `$("#DisplayModal").replaceWith(partialViewResult);`. Now I can see the modal. But I am not sure whether this is the way to do this. Please suggest me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177072/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mvc).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Link

```
<a href="/Home/_ModalPopup?Page=1" class="modal-link"> Open</a>
```

Script

```
$('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
        $('#modal-container').removeData('bs.modal');
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
        $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#modal-content').html(data);
            $('#modal-container').modal('show');
        });


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="DisplayModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, Model.CategoriesList, ID="DPCategoriesList" new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>               
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$('#DPCategoriesList').on("change", function () {  
            var CategoriesList = $('#DPCategoriesList').val();  
            var obj = { CategoriesList: CategoriesList };  
            AjaxCall('url', JSON.stringify(obj),'POST').done(function (response) {  
                if (response) {  
                     $('#modal-content').html(response);
            $('#modal-container').modal('show');

                }  
            }).fail(function (error) {  
                alert(error.StatusText);  
            });  
        });
```

Comment: code does not work. While posting the answer please use my code and modify if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Many many thanks to @StephenMuecke for his guidance. His guidance helped me to solve this dropdown dynamic load problem. This is simple script which appends data inside dropdown.

```
$(document).on("click", '.LinkId', function () {
            var url = $(this).data("url");
            var Category = $("#Category");
            $.getJSON(url, { id: $(this).val() }, function (response) {
                Category.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
                $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                    Category.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
                });
                $('#DisplayModal').modal('show');
            });
        })
```